# Запуск большого количества потоков

Tags: python, многопоточность

Написал маленькую тестилку к своему сайту, но примерно на 1000 потоке питон говорит, что не может запустить больше:

> can't start new thread

Есть, конечно, решения, отпочковать процесс или писать несколько запросов в один поток, но если кто знает, как увеличить максимальное количество потоков в питоне, был бы рад выслушать.

Гугл мне не очень помог, возможно, в силу слабого знания английского.

Comment: нужно больше золота

а если серьезно - для нагрузочного тестирования есть готовые инструменты, jmeter, apache benchmarks, объединяющий несколько утилит яндекс.танк.

Comment: @mi8882255, вообще-то говоря, плодить очень много потоков для создания высокой нагрузки -- это не самая хорошая идея. 

Если говорить о pthreads в Linux, то действительно можно создавать много тысяч потоков, устанавливая `pthread_attr_setdetachstate()`, но, например,  join к ним уже не применим... (правда, не знаю, что там реализовано в питоне с подобными тонкими настройками, да и есть ли там уже настоящие threads (раньше, насколько помню, потоками там называли процессы -- т.е. результат fork-а)).

А лучше напишите, что Вы на самом деле хотите делать из своей маленькой тестилки.

Comment: Ну вобщем то ничего сложного, регистрация от 100-ни пользователей, получение 100 кук и дальше, кидать несколько тысяч (жсон) запросов по разным адресам, единственно что в перспективе хочу к ним прикрутить небольшую логику в зависимости от данных которые вернуло (жсон).

На текущий момент прикрутил запускающую приложушку которая запускает десяток програмулин по 100 потоков паралельно(работает, но хотелось бы в рамках одной програмки это все крутить но не хватает потоков, хоть бери и на жаве переписуй... там вроде такой проблемы небыло, знай только Xmm поднимай ...)

Comment: Не нужно создавать тысячи потоков, только чтобы создать тысячи сетевых соединений, можно использовать асинхронный ввод/вывод посредством [gevent, asycnio, twisted библиотек](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4783735/4279), etc -- что по вкусу.


@avp потоки в Питоне -- настоящие OS потоки. Вам возможно не совсем удачный перевод попался. В некоторый книгах по параллельному программированию (не имеет отношения к Питону) не различают как параллелизм реализован (processes, threads) и одно слово используют, иногда это оправдано если нас не интересуют различия, а интерфейс практически идентичен.

Comment: Хорошо бы еще ОС знать. Кажется, что не в интерпретаторе ограничение.